# How to get a success callback in realm db kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, realm, realm-mobile-platform

After saving the data to realmdb what is the success callback?

```
val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder(setOf(ContactLocalModel::class)).build()

private val realm : Realm = Realm.open(config)

viewModel.onSaveButtonClick.observe(this){
        val contacts = realm.query(ContactLocalModel::class)

        if(!binding.groupEditText.text.isNullOrEmpty() && !binding.pttEditNum.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
            val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {

                realm.writeBlocking {
                    try{
                        copyToRealm(ContactLocalModel().apply {
                            name = binding.groupEditText.text.toString()
                            pttNo = binding.pttEditNum.text.toString()
                           
                        })
                       
                   
                    } catch (e: Exception){
                        e.toString()
                    }
                }
            }
            job.cancel()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Empty fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

On tap of a button the data is getting saved. How to get a success callback, after that i need to navigate back

Comment: Where are you expecting/want a success callback. Here `copyToRealm(ContactLocalModel().apply`? From the docs - *Pass the new object instance to `copyToRealm()` to persist the object data to the realm. This method returns a managed instance of the object. You can modify the persisted object through the returned instance*. [Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/crud/create/)